MP3 Player Timestamp Tag/Marker
I'm not really sure what to name this thing I'm looking for, but I've been recording my classes and playing them at home to study. It's hard to go back to topics, and most of my time is consumed just finding which timestamp/topic I'm looking for in one recording. (Mind you, these are multiple days/lessons so there's A LOT.)
Maybe y'all know some app I can download where I can add tags/note on timestamps so I can just go back to them without any hassle. I'd really appreciate any suggestions or help I'll get here. TIA!!

Welcome Jeanne! Good question! Do you have an OS requirement?  How about a price requirement (or gratis)?  If so, can you please edit you question and tags to reflect them?  Thanks, and again, welcome!
